# How do you configure CORS for specific origins using ASP.NET Core 6 Web API?

Tags: .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have read through several posts with similar errors, and have tried almost every permutation of configurations and suggested answers in the posts, to no avail.

I have enabled CORS according to the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I am using the middleware option, specifically a named policy.

The error I get in the javascript console is this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://hotsauceodds.azurewebsites.net/api/glue/auth/ccb112d8-a2a8-4a1d-8786-b481889888f4' from origin 'https://monumental-fairy-0fe0e5.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Oddly enough, the SignalR connection works.

It is only the Ajax request that is failing, from this URL:

```
https://monumental-fairy-0fe0e5.netlify.app
```

However, I have added these configurations according to the docs:

```
using ArbWeb.TimerFeatures;
using DataAccess;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Models.HubConfig;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://monumental-fairy-0fe0e5.netlify.app")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<TimerManager>();

builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options => {
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
    {
        ValidationProblemDetails error = actionContext.ModelState
            .Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
            .Select(e => new ValidationProblemDetails(actionContext.ModelState)).FirstOrDefault();

        return new BadRequestObjectResult(error);
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapHub<BroadcastHub>("/arb");

HotsauceOddsRepo.Initialize();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Did it work with the localhost:4200?
Have you tried using a default policy instead of named policy?
When you say this is the only request failing from this URL, are other requests to the API from the same URL working, i.e., is there only 1 specific endpoint facing this issue?

Comment: @sourvad thanks for responding. I found that the cause of the CORS error was actually an unrelated internal error in the API, caused by the environment change (local to azure). I had read about this and wrapped the code in a try/catch to see if this were the case, but nothing was logged in the azure live stream, so I thought it was CORS.

Comment: Please try to [enable cors with attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#enable-cors-with-attributes), and I am waiting for your update.

Comment: @JasonPan thanks for replying, Jason. The CORS error logged in the js console was a red herring. It was actually an unhandled exception in the API. For some reason, it was logged as a CORS error, though. Once the exception was handled, the CORS errors stopped